# Why didn't they add an operator version of iota?

Tags: c++, c++11, iota

The iota template function was added to the standard library to fill an iterator range with an increasing sequence of values.

```
  template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Tp>
    void
    iota(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Tp value)
    {
      for (; first != last; ++first)
        {
          *first = value;
          ++value;
        }
    }
```

Most other templates in `<numeric>` have versions that accept user-specified operators.
Having this:

```
  template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Tp, typename Operator>
    void
    iota(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Tp value, Operator op)
    {
      for (; first != last; ++first)
        {
          *first = value;
          op(value);
        }
    }
```

would be convenient if you don't want to (or can't) overload operator++() for Tp. I would find this version more widely usable than the default operator++() version.
<

Comment: You're right, with lambdas the second version is not only more flexible than the first, but almost as easy to use for increment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lambdas, the second version doesn't save much, you can just use `std::generate`.

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Tp, typename Operator>
void iota(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Tp value, Operator op)
{
  std::generate(first, last, [&value,&op](){auto v = value; op(value); return v;});
}
```

In fact, this makes the existing implementation of `std::iota` very redundant:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Tp>
void iota(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Tp value)
{
  std::generate(first, last, [&value](){return value++;});
}
```

Comment: True, iota probably just blesses the SGI version which is distributed by gcc as an extension and probably other implementations.

Comment: `partial_sum` is even better (no `[&]`). `vector<int> i(10,0); partial_sum(i.begin(),i.end(),i.begin(),[](int p, int c) {return p++;}`

Comment: @kirill: Nearly so.  But `partial_sum` doesn't accept a `value` parameter to seed the accumulation.  Also the `++` postincrement in your code snippet is useless... the updated value of `p` is discarded immediately.  In fact, your code snippet is totally wrong, and doesn't create an increasing sequence at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt @kirill_igum thanks, it should be `++p`. now it works. you can also modify the lambda function or have [&value]. the main point is that's another way. you can use it if you want something quick and don't want to make another function.

Comment: @kirill: It should be `p+1`.  But `std::generate` works quite well already, and gives the flexibility in starting value that `partial_sum` doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the reason is the usual mix of one or more of the following reasons:

- No one submitted a proposal
- It wasn't considered important enough for *this* version (which was already *huge*, and very late)
- it fell through the cracks and was forgotten (like `copy_if` in C++98)
- it is easy to replace using `std::generate`.